# SQL Job failing when one of the steps attempts to connect to another server

Tags: sql, sql-job

I have created a job where step 1 calls for the deletion of data from table1 on server "ucpdapps2".  Step 2 calls to pull data from table5 on server "archive" and place it in table1 on server "ucpdapps2".  When I run the job step 1 works but step 2 fails with the error [image]

I don't even have a user called UCPDAPPS2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  It kept bothering me the error kept showing the user as ucpdapps2$ and that no such user existed.  So after some reading, the server creates itself as a user. So seeing how the job is run under that server I figured maybe that is the user name that must have rights in the archive server even though I linked the two servers to talk to one another.  So I just added that user under the security/login tab under the archive server.